# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at FirebaseCrashlytics.initialise

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, crashlytics

Ionic firebase Crashlytics not working, given error.

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at FirebaseCrashlytics.initialise

I have followed ionic docs,https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-crashlytics

can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: You may get better support on integration issues when using Cordova here: https://github.com/ReallySmallSoftware/cordova-plugin-firebase-crashlytics/issues